# Reverse Sort (for date) by _id not working with MeteorJS Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Any idea why this isn't sorting in reverse chronological order (based on date created)?
`myPosts.find({}, {sort: {_id: -1}}).fetch()`

This works, however I read not to trust it for sorting by date created.

`Tweets.find().fetch().reverse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_id` field is a randomized hash, you shouldn't use it for sorting. Instead, you should insert the date into the document:

```
Tweets.insert({
  content: 'Blah blah blah',
  dateCreated: new Date()
});
```

And then `Tweets.find({}, {sort: {dateCreated: -1}})`. Remember to not use `.fetch()` unless you actually want an array of objects. If you're returning from a Meteor helper function or related context, don't use `.fetch()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the Meteor docs:

> ObjectID values created by Meteor will not have meaningful answers to their getTimestamp method, since Meteor currently constructs them fully randomly.

See [Mongo.ObjectID](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id). Thus a sorting by date via `_id` should not work.